# Outlook rewrites all links in my email to go through Microsoft servers

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

One of my email providers recently switched to providing the mail service via MS Outlook. Then, a few weeks ago, all of my mail messages started having their web links rewritten - to go through `https://eur01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com`.

I don't want this; I don't need this; and it messes up my emails. Instead of archiving the mail messages I was sent, I only have access to rewritten emails by Microsoft!

Is there a way to bypass/overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to bypass/overcome this?

Yes.

> **Can I turn off Safelinks?**
>
> To provide the best protection for your account, Safelinks are on by
>   default. You can turn them off by signing in to
>   [https://outlook.live.com](https://outlook.live.com/). Then select Settings > Premium >
>   Security. There's a toggle under Advanced Security that you can use to
>   turn off Safelinks. Note that turning off Safelinks will only affect
>   future messages you receive. It won't change the link format in
>   messages you've already received.

Source[Advanced Outlook.com security for Office 365 subscribers - Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/advanced-outlook-com-security-for-office-365-subscribers-882d2243-eab9-4545-a58a-b36fee4a46e2)

Comment: My Outlook is accessible under outlook.office.com, and there are no "Premium" settings there...

Comment: @einpoklum Then ask your email provider to fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In a corporate environment, Safelink (ATP) feature can NOT been disabled by employees. This is a disaster, because in all e-mails replies, the personalized bandworm URLs are included.
In the URL starting with https://che01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?...
there is also the individual e-mail-address of employee included.
That is an absolute NoGo (privacy, tracking) and destroys the intention with tiny/simple URLs, which might be quite relevant for the e-mail receiver.

Comment: This is a useful comment, but not quite an answer.